# Cannot Access Windows Shared Folder with IP but can using hostname

Tags: windows, ip, registry, hostname, shared-directory

While Trying to reach Shared Folder with IP Address getting Error as shown here [Error Message where trying with IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBNjs.png).

Can Access by using hostname.

We can access by using hostname.

It Happens frequently, sometimes restarting Shared Folder Host PC helps, but again same error occurs. But I can access by hostname. The issue is several clients access only with IP, including several printers uses this shared folder for storing scanned documents. Need permanent fix for this.

I have tried all the ipconfig stuff: flush, release, renew. I tried editing Regedit as shown in below,

https://superuser.com/questions/1240213/cannot-connect-to-windows-share-via-local-network-ip-address-but-can-by-localho

Still issue persists. Need permanent solution for this issue, rather than restart Host, flushdns.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is somthing wrong with the path of the shared folder, please write the full/correct path of the shared ressource and try again

Comment: It was working fine with the IP address i.e. \\10.26.8.77 but suddenly now it gives error.